# Trigger Error Handling

Tags: trigger, error, after-trigger

I have an after update trigger on Account which updates the child contacts Industry field.

Sample Code:

```java
Trigger accountTrigger on Account(After Update){
    Map<Id, Account> acMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.newMap){
        acMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
    }

    List<Contact> updatedList = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Industry FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :acMap.keySet()];
    for(Contact con: conList){
        if(con.Industry__c != 'IT'){
            con.Industry = 'IT';
            updatedList.add(con);
        }
    }

    if(!updatedList.isEmpty()){
        update updatedList;
    }
}
```

Now what if the updatedList update DML operation fails, we will not want the Account changes also in that scenario. How can we achieve this?

Comment: For your reference: You do not need to check to see if a list is empty before performing DML. Salesforce is smart enough to not count it against the DML operations limit if there are no rows to update. Also, since you're not using `conList` anywhere else, you could save some typing and put the query into the `for()` statement itself (e.g. `for(Contact con : [SELECT ...]){`)

Comment: Got it. I will keep that in mind
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any part of a transaction fails without the error being handled then the entire transaction is automatically failed.

An error can be handled by catching an exception, or where an error is added to an `SObject` or field during trigger processing using `addError` by using an `allOrNone` value of `false` in the `Database` DML call.

Since you appear to have neither, the account updates will be aborted if there are errors raised (exception or `addError`) during the updating of the contacts.

NB: validation rule failures are equivalent to `addError`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!
So its like if no error handling is written, it will abort even the account update since it comes under the same transaction?
If possible can you please add the code for error handling with a best approach in this scenario?

Comment: That is what happens, and this probably is what you want to happen here; if you try to handle the errors, the contacts won't be updated but the changes to the account will be applied and you'll have inconsistent state in the DB. In most scenarios, it is best to leave error handling to the Salesforce Platform (by allowing exceptions to propagate back out, and by using DML with `allOrNone` as `true`) since this means everything in the failed transaction will be cleanly rolled back. This means you'll have consistent data in the DB.

Comment: Got it.
Thank you